# Deploying SAP standard fiori application as a custom fiori application

Tags: sapui5, element, sap-fiori

I had a requirement to add custom logic in SAP standard fiori application and deploy it as a custom application. it's Application Type is Transactional (SAP Fiori elements). i couldn't use extension project or Adaptation project to make my changes. it is showing an error (Extending smart application is currently not supported). So i have made changes in application as it was already extended by SAP (it have "ext" folder in it also have reference in manifest.json) and working fine in Webide.

So i deployed that application as a New application and gave different application ID. In SE80 BSP application it is displaying my changes. But very same application changes are not being reflected on Fiori launchpad.

please let me know if more information is required.

i have used following blogs for my reference.

[Standard Application Link in Fiori Application Library](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F2428')/S14OP)

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/01/14/adaptation-projects-a-tutorial/comment-page-1/#comment-464401

https://ga.support.sap.com/dtp/viewer/index.html#/tree/1910/actions/24709:24711 (Extending CDS wont fulfill requirement)

https://www.slideshare.net/MayankGupta290/extending-adaptation-project-from-sap-webide

https://help.sap.com/fiori_bs2013/helpdata/en/c1/804352b4e61b13e10000000a44176d/frameset.htm

Comment: It sounds like a possible caching issue.
There might be several steps involved for clearing caches, e.g. regarding UI2 cache: “Run report /UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES. This cache clearing is mandatory especially to verify the translations integrated for ex tiles,groups,catalogs in Launchpad admin.” Please try to clear caches as seen here https://answers.sap.com/questions/11411715/sap-fiori-launchpad-caching.html ,
here https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/02/cache-maintenance-in-fiori/ 
and here https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/16/sap-fiori-cache-management/ .

Comment: already tried, still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved by just deleting component preload  files from webIde.
and deploying it again.
Thanks all :)